# How to bypass the system proxy when using WebClient

Tags: c#

I am using proxy in the window

[image]

How to by pass the proxy server setting using webclient while uploading or downloading from some website. Even i am using the proxy server in the control panel.

Comment: I've removed your wpf tag for you.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: No worries :) Happy to help.

Comment: hassan does my answer solve your problem?

Comment: i am trying but not working :(

Comment: Does it give you an exception?

Comment: it shows, the class has been deprecated.

Comment: Trust Microsoft to not update their documentation. Apparently Ahmad's way is the correct way of doing it now. I've provided [feedback](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/5413) to Microsoft about the documentation so hopefully they'll update it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this

```
WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
webclient.Proxy = null;
```

it will resolve your issue

Comment: just removed space between webclient and (.)