# WebClient.DownloadData times out on server after moving to AWS

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, webclient, google-maps-static-api

In an ASP.NET MVC webapp I developed years ago in C#, there is an action / controller that downloads an image of Google maps and saves it to disk for later use, using `WebClient.DownloadData`.

This action / controller is requested 4 or 5 times a day. This web app (and the action / controller) worked perfectly in development and production (in-house server, Windows Server 2008 R2 Foundation, IIS 7.5, .NET Framework v4.0).

Recently, the app was moved to a new virtual server in AWS (Windows Server 2019 Datacenter, IIS 10, .NET CLR v4.0). The whole web app seems to work fine except for the action / controller that I mentioned previously.

If I use the URL in chrome installed in the new virtual server the map is downloaded without issues. But when the action / controller is requested it times out (exception):

[image: exception]

The code is simple:

```
string url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?key=[API_KEY]&center=" + lat + "," + long + "&size=355x255&markers=color:red|" + lat + "," + long;
WebClient web = new WebClient();
byte[] bs = web.DownloadData(url);
// save bs in disk
```

This is an example of a map that it should be downloaded

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?key=[API_KEY]&center=25.670984,-100.285016&size=355x255&markers=color:red|25.670984,-100.285016
```

[image: static map]

I checked the `WebClient.DownloadData` documentation and I haven't found any hint of what can cause the problem.

Again, this action / controller worked perfectly fine for years but after the migration it started to fail.

---

### More info

---

I build a console application which contains only the next code (using different API_KEYs without limitations):

```
WebClient web = new WebClient();
byte[] bs = web.DownloadData("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?key=API_KEY&center=25.670984,-100.285016&size=355x255&markers=color:red|25.670984,-100.285016");
File.WriteAllBytes("mapa.jpg", bs);
```

And still got Timeout Exception.

Then, I installed mitmproxy to monitor the traffic (maybe it was a problem with the network?) and it worked perfectly.

Code using the proxy (changed https to http):

```
WebClient web = new WebClient();
WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1", 8080);
byte[] bs = web.DownloadData("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?key=API_KEY&center=25.670984,-100.285016&size=355x255&markers=color:red|25.670984,-100.285016");
File.WriteAllBytes("mapa.jpg", bs);
```

BUT I can't let mitmproxy running all the time in the server, something is still off.

Comment: Don't use that obsolete class. It's been fully replaced by HttpClient. It was never meant to be used with APIs, it was created as a component one could put on a Windows Form application to download files and make simple GETs and POSTs

Comment: I get it, but this is a ancient code and worked fine. Do you have any idea what can be the problem here? Maybe permissions or configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem: was the default proxy of the server.

Thanks to this question [How to bypass the system proxy when using WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50364690/1574639) the path to the solution was there.

```
WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
webclient.Proxy = null;
```

According to the [WebClient.Proxy Property documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.proxy?view=net-6.0):

> The proxy is set by the system using configuration files and the
> Internet Explorer Local Area Network settings. To specify that no
> proxy should be used, set the Proxy property to null.

And the default proxy of the server (AWS) does not allow the request that I was trying to perform.

Now, because I can not modify the code (right now) in the webapp (action/controller), I had to search [How to disable proxy server via web.config file](http://chris.gg/2010/03/how-to-disable-proxy-server-via-web-config-file/) and it worked.

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy>
    <proxy usesystemdefault="False"/>
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Obviously, the value was "True" and changed it to "False".